# Open new tab for pagereference, i dont have a command button cannot use 'Target' attribute

Tags: visualforce, custom-button, pagereference

thanks @kevan

When the User clicks on the Custom link on a page layout,  new tab should open routing to the url as formulated in the controller.
VF page is behind the custom link. I dont want to use a JAVASCRIPT, as we are in the verge of moving towards lightining.

Targer attribute (command button and link ) or javascript (windows.open) wont work out.

VF Page

```
<apex:page standardController="Asset" extensions="LaunchAssetButtons_CTRL" action="{!launchCTMOBRequest}" >
<apex:pageMessages ></apex:pageMessages>
<apex:outputPanel >
<script> window.open('{!url}', '_blank'); </script>
</apex:outputPanel>
<apex:sectionHeader title="Open Salesforce Case and Pop Page"/>   
<apex:outputPanel >If you see this page
</apex:outputPanel> 
</apex:page>
```

Contoller method

```
public string url {get;set;} 

Public string launchCTMOBRequest(){
url = 'www.google.com';
return url;
}
```

This VF page is the the engine behind the of a custom link. enter image description here
[image]

when ever i click on this link , a new tab should open with the above URl. I want to use only VF page not JAVA script button.

Can someone please help ?

Comment: Your requirement is not clear, am bit confused on what you want to achieve.

Comment: Please see [ask] to get the most from the Community. There's way too much code posted here as most of it is irrelevant to your issue. Simplify your problem to its essence

Comment: You need to use either target or JavaScript. You can't specify a target in the PageReference class. There simply is no other way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have achieved the above requirement , while creating the custom button , we can choose 'Open in new window' option and this solves my problem.

Thank you all for your valuable time :-)
Venkatesh

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend the following changes in your code. 
Instead of returning a pagereference assign the link to a variable.

```
public string url {get;set;}
```

Then in your visualforce page, add the following code:

```
<apex:outputPanel rendered="{! NOT(ISBLANK(url)) }">
<script> window.open("{!url}", "_blank"); </script>
</apex:outputPanel>
```

So when your action is executed and populate the "url" variable, it should redirect to your url.

Hope it helps. 
Check my blog for tips and tricks about Salesforce
https://kevansfdc.blogspot.com